# How to display 10 objects using configuration file

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

Suppose we have a class, and it contains few members. We make a few objects of the class, and we only want to display a limited number of objects, how can we do this using configuration file?

Comment: What do you mean by *display*? In VisualStudio, in IntelliSense, in your application etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a app setting variable in configuration file for example "app:items_to_show"=4 Then you can limit your list of objects to that value present in configuration file using LINQ
for example

```
var no_of_items = 
  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["app:items_to_show"];

List<foo> myList=new List<foo>();

//code that will populate the list

//Take the First n of items define in configuration File
myList = myList.Take(no_of_items);
```

now `myList` will have `n` of items you require

Comment: what is the use of configuration file here. we can do this without the configuration file. but i specifically want to use config files

Comment: Yes you can hard code the no of items, but since you mentioned to use configuration file, it will help you to change the no of items on fly without rebuilding your solution. If your project is a web application than Web.config can have the app settings otherwise App.config file  can be used for other project types.